# Why helm chart cannot be install on Microk8s?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3, microk8s

I am using microk8s to run Kubernetes on my Ubuntu server. I am using the helm v3 as my helm command.

This is the result of the `helm version` command:

> version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.9.2", GitCommit:"1addefbfe665c350f4daf868a9adc5600cc064fd", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.17.12"}

I am trying to run this helm chart on this K8s instance:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: myTest
description: The test daemon (test) helm chart
type: application
version: 1.4.0
appVersion: v1.18.0
kubeVersion: ">= 1.19.0"
...
```

But I am getting this error:

> INSTALLATION FAILED: chart requires kubeVersion: >= 1.19.0 which is incompatible with Kubernetes v1.19.15-34+c064bb32deff78

I tried different versions of Microk8s as 1.21, 1.24, and 1.19 but there is the same result.

I installed this service on minikube without any problem :(

Comment: try update the microk8s via `snap`, then: `microk8s enable helm`

Comment: I did that, I enabled helm and helm3. version 1.24 is the latest channel that you can install by using snap but nothing resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Semantic Versioning specification](https://semver.org) you have a [pre-release version](https://semver.org/#spec-item-9) of Kubernetes.  (This is possibly an issue in microk8s's release process.)  The Helm documentation for [the `kubeVersion:` field](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#the-kubeversion-field) states that it depends on the Go [github.com/Masterminds/semver](https://github.com/Masterminds/semver) package.  [Its documentation](https://github.com/Masterminds/semver#working-with-prerelease-versions) notes:

> SemVer comparisons using constraints without a prerelease comparator will skip prerelease versions. For example, `>=1.2.3` will skip prereleases when looking at a list of releases while `>=1.2.3-0` will evaluate and find prereleases.

So setting in your `Chart.yaml` that you're willing to tolerate pre-release versions should address this:

```yaml
kubeVersion: ">= 1.19.0-0" # adding a -0 on the end
```